# combine several surfaces to a single closed mesh

Tags: mesh

I used Paraview to take different slices and contours of a 3D data set. So each step produces one surface mesh. In my case, three surfaces together enclose a volume (just like 6 surfaces make a cube). However, for 3D printing, these three surfaces understandably have zero volume because they are not connected.

For a cube out of 6 sides, that would be quickly done node-by-node, but my surface is quite detailed, see screenshot. Is there a way to "close the gaps" and make this mesh of 3 surfaces an actual volumetric object instead of 3 surfaces?

As you see I selected a loop around one of the surfaces and there exists and almost-identical loop in the other surface which should be merged, but they are not perfectly identical, there are holes on the lower right[image].

Comment: That foreground surface looks flat. Is that always the case?

Comment: this fron side cut is flat, there is another spherical cut, so that surface is not flat

Comment: Maybe try in Edit mode to enable the Auto Merge option and the Split Edges & Faces option, then select all, press G and Enter right away, and increase the Threshold until the surfaces merge, then check if the object is now manifold

Comment: actually this seems to have done the trick. No more complaints from the 3D printer. Let's hope it prints well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in *Edit* mode to enable the *Auto Merge* option and the *Split Edges & Faces* option, then select all, press <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away, and increase the *Threshold* until the surfaces merge, then check if the object is now manifold:

[image]

Comment: thank you. The 3D print addon also helped clean up the mesh.